# Setting a breakpoint in pycharm changes the behavior of the code

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, pycharm

That's really a Pycharm - IDE question - the python/wx bug is fixed.

A seemingly innocuous change broke the `raceText.SetLabel()` call (which simply sets the text in the static text control) below. So I set a breakpoint in `item = self.items[itemDex]`:

```
def __init__(self):
    # ...
    self.raceText  = staticText(self,u'') # see below for staticText definition

def EvtListBox(self,event):
    """Responds to listbox selection."""
    itemDex = event.GetSelection()
    item = self.items[itemDex] # breakpoint here
    face = self.data[item]
    self.nameText.SetLabel(face.pcName)
    self.raceText.SetLabel(face.getRaceName()) # this
```

Lo and behold `self.raceText.SetLabel(face.getRaceName())` now succeeded.

So how is this possible ? What does setting a breakpoint trigger ?

EDIT: some more data:

What originally broke the SetLabel() call was this commit:

```
-def staticText(parent,label=u'',pos=defPos,size=defSize,style=0,name=u"staticText",id=defId,):
+def staticText(parent, label=u'', pos=defPos, size=defSize, style=0,
+               noAutoResize=True, name=u"staticText"):
     """Static text element."""
-    return wx.StaticText(parent,id,label,pos,size,style,name)
+    if noAutoResize: style |= wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE
+    return wx.StaticText(parent, defId, label, pos, size, style, name)
```

Flipping noAutoResize default value to False squashed the bug - the text was set but `wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE` would prevent the control to adjust its size from `u''` - so no text was displayed. So this was a plain old bug.

The question remains *why on earth when setting a breakpoint in the debugger `self.raceText.SetLabel()` shows the text* ?

EDIT: do read the answer - sanity check

Comment: If you tell PyCharm to continue, does the UI update correctly? What OS are you on? Do you have a small runnable example of the code?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: Yes it updates the ui correctly that's the point - `(<wx._controls.StaticText; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxStaticText *' at 0x7a506d8> >, u'Breton')` is the arguments to the SetLabel call. No small runnable example sorry - here is the code: https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/blob/f53adcad7f0af0867545476474d85b57b8bb3d36/Mopy/bash/basher/dialogs.py#L428-L441

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding. The breakpoint is causing `self.raceText.SetLabel()` not to be called, correct? And the breakpoint is BEFORE that line, correct? If so, then that's exactly what should happen. Breakpoints pause execution when they are reached so you can do debugging.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: No the opposite: when I run the debugger and put no breakpoint the UI is NOT updated correctly. So I put a breakpoint to see what the heck is going on and it hits the breakpoint, everything looks normal - I hit F8 - execution goes on and the UI is updated correctly !

Comment: What happens if you don't run the debugger but just run it normally? Does it work then? If so, then this sounds like it might be a bug on PyCharm's side.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: it does not work - that's why I run the debugger :D Yes - it's strange - the bug is fixed later on so it is mostly for this strange behavior I post it

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: alright edited to clarify and added more info. Debugger _crawls_ but I verified it - adding a breakpoint and stepping into the code makes it work - while not stepping in debugger and normal execution do not display the text (as they should according to the docs for [wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.StaticText.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, I think it's possible that running in the debugger is simply hiding or confusing the real issue.

When wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE *is not* set then changes to the label will cause the widget's size to be adjusted, which will typically cause the widget to be repainted soon via an automatic paint event from the system.  When wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE *is* set, then the resize doesn't happen and so that particular paint event doesn't happen and the widget may not get repainted until the next time the parent is refreshed or something else happens that triggers a paint event.

So a likely fix would be to add a call to `self.fooText.Refresh()` after each `SetLabel`.  The display will still not be updated while stopped in the debugger because the paint event normally won't happen until return to the active event loop, but in a normal run it will happen soon enough that the user will not notice unless there is some long-running thing blocking the return to the event loop.

Comment: The strange thing is that the paint event _is_ fired in the debugger - but your explanation sheds some light at least - apparently something in the debugger hocus pocus fires such an event while in normal execution is not - closing EDIT: now I think about it it's trivial ahahaha - the breakpoint switches focus to the IDE - then back to program -> paint - rolfmao